# Find Probability Distribution Parameters For Sample With Percentage Given

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm having trouble understanding how to map out parameters of a probability distribution when given sample size & a percentage, I'm unsure how to explain the issue so I've made up an example, I didn't want to use the actual problem so I can solve it myself after I learn how:

> For each store, the store manager randomly selects 20 phones to check
>   if they are faulty each week. He then reports the number of faulty
>   phones to the store owner. Let X represent the number of faulty phones
>   reported in a given week from a store where 20% of all phones are
>   faulty.
>
> State the probability distribution of X (including the values of all
>   parameters)

My initial guess would be:

- P(X=1) = 0.2
- P(X=2) = 0.2 * 0.2 = 0.04
- P(X=3) = 0.2 * 0.2 * 0.2 = 0.008

And so on, but I'm not sure how I'm meant to nicely show the values of all the parameters, do I just show it as P(X) = 0.2^X ?

My other issue with the solution is that the sample size doesn't factor into the answer, which does not seem correct to me.

If you've got any links related to the theory in approaching this problem that would be much appreciated as well.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Okay, so I think I've got it now.. P(X) = (n! / (n – X)! X!) * p^X * (1-p)^(n-X)